# Normal Sylow subgroup P has a complement in G (no Schur–Zassenhaus)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

If we consider a finite group G, a prime p, and we suppose that the Sylow p-subgroup P is normal in G, we know by Schur-Zassenhaus that $G\cong P\rtimes G/P$.

Is there an elementary way to see it? In particular, I'd like to identify the complement subgroup in $G$ which is isomorphic to $G/P$. I was pretty sure that this was just an easy check if we use Sylow Thms, but I haven't managed to see it so far. 
Thanks!

Comment: It is not difficult to prove the existence of complement part of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem if you assume this result. So proving it is no easier than proving the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Comment: The proof of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem uses induction on the group order, and the proof starts off by reducing to the case when the normal subgroup is an elementary abelian $p$-group for soem prime $p$. This reduction is straightforward. It is hadnling this case that is the more difficult part of the proof, which involves an averaging argument. Since this case is also a special case of ypur question, it follows that your question is not significantly easier than the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem itself.

Comment: The main trouble in Schur-Zassenhaus is when normal Hall-subgroup is "abelian", and in that case, it automatically implies that Sylow subgroups of this abelian normal subgroup are also normal Sylow subgroups of $G$; still no simplication in proof is there, I guess.